# Why does this simple php script crash?

Tags: php

Running this on my local wamp server gives me `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` when trying to access the .php file through a browser. Whats going on here?

```
<?php
$catalog = simplexml_load_file('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml');

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['selection'])) {
    $_SESSION['selection'] = array();
}

array_push($_SESSION['selection'], $catalog->CD[0]);
?>
```

here is a piece of the output of `var_dump($catalog)`

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
  public 'CD' => 
    array (size=26)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
          public 'TITLE' => string 'Empire Burlesque' (length=16)
          public 'ARTIST' => string 'Bob Dylan' (length=9)
          public 'COUNTRY' => string 'USA' (length=3)
          public 'COMPANY' => string 'Columbia' (length=8)
          public 'PRICE' => string '10.90' (length=5)
          public 'YEAR' => string '1985' (length=4)
      1 => [...]
```

EDIT:
Found this from looking in the apache log as suggested:

```
[Tue Apr 02 09:34:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in [no active file]:0\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in [no active file] on line 0
```

So i guess the problem is that php's session serialization doesnt allow SimpleXMLElements. I'll save an index or something instead.

Comment: Have you debugged it? Or eliminated line-by-line to get the minimal cause?

Comment: What happens when you download the xml file and access it locally?

Comment: i dont know how to go into debug mode in php, but the cause is in the last line, where a SimpleXMLElement is pushed to an array. I can push a normal string onto the array, or an object i defined myself, but when try to push an object from the $catalog-CD array, it crashes or something.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/74313/what-could-cause-an-101-error-in-wamp-under-windows-7

Comment: same thing happens when i access the xml file locally

Comment: This is the curse of www.w3schools.com...

Comment: As you know, SimpleXMLElement objects cannot be passed through serialize(). Store the XML as a string in the session, using ...->asXML()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert something on top your program like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_log', 'phperror.log');
ini_set('log_errors_max_len', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
```

and look at error file after error.